# Capistrano deploy, http error 503

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, capistrano3

Using capistrano for deploying on server nginx+puma. But for some reason if i access the page too quickly, or if somebody is on the page, it gives a 503 HTTP Error page. They I usually just redeploy again and again until it works or i either kill Puma and redeploy again to see if that fixed it. I imagine there is a better way to do this? Or is my deploying process missing something?

```
  gem 'capistrano', '~> 3.10.0', require: false
  gem 'capistrano-rails', require: false
  gem 'capistrano-bundler', require: false
  gem 'capistrano-rvm', require: false
  gem 'capistrano3-puma', '~> 3.1', '>= 3.1.1', require: false
  gem 'capistrano-rails-console', require: false
  gem 'capistrano-rake', require: false

# Load DSL and set up stages
require "capistrano/setup"

# Include default deployment tasks
require "capistrano/deploy"

require "capistrano/scm/git"
install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Git

require 'capistrano/rvm'
require 'capistrano/bundler'
require 'capistrano/rails/assets' # for asset handling add
require 'capistrano/rails/migrations' # for running migrations

require 'capistrano/puma'
install_plugin Capistrano::Puma  # Default puma tasks
install_plugin Capistrano::Puma::Workers
install_plugin Capistrano::Puma::Nginx

require 'capistrano/rails/console'
require "whenever/capistrano"
require 'capistrano/rake'

Dir.glob("lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake").each { |r| import r }
```

Comment: Can you post the contents of your `Capfile`?

Comment: @SeanHuber added